# In my Blazor server app, I want to show messages of razor.cs pages in the header. But I cannot pass the messages from the razor pages to the header

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

I have a Blazor server side app (.Net7) consisting of sidebar, header and body sections. In the body section there can be navigated to several razor pages over the sidebar.
In all razor pages there are generated some error messages related to the page functions. All these error messages should be shown in the common header part.The header part contains the razor page "razor_header".

I have written the code below in the mentioned pages, but I cannot pass the error messages correctly from the razor pages to the header razor page. Although the error messages are generated (I can check this over a log file) I see them not immediatly in the header page. Mostly they are shown delayed, on other events. What is missing in my code? I am not so good in Blazor server side. I think I am missing some basic stuff. I thought that the binding in Blazor is working also between pages. But i think this is not the case.

My razor_header page

```
@inject TagService TagService
<div>
    <h2>@TagService.Message_Main</h2>        
</div>
```

My razor_page_1.cs (@inject TagService TagService in rel.razor page)

```
public async Task Task_1() 
{
//some code
if(error1_condition==true)
  {
  TagService.Message_Main=error1_text; //error1 should be shown in the header
  StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

My razor_page_2.cs (@inject TagService TagService in rel.razor page)

```
 public async Task Task_2() 
 {
 //some code
 if(error2_condition==true)
  {
  TagService.Message_Main=error2_text; //error2 should be shown in the header
  StateHasChanged();
  }
 }
```

My razor_page_3.cs  (@inject TagService TagService in rel.razor page)

```
public async Task Task_3() 
{
//some code    
if(error3_condition==true)
  {
  TagService.Message_Main=error3_text; //error3 should be shown in the header
  StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear how `TagService` is being instantiated. Are you using dependency injection? Parameters?

Comment: @Frosch  TagService is  a scoped service where I have defined all the client specific tags. Yes in all razor pages there is dependency injection to TagService. Have updated all the example pages regardingly, for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement what is commonly known as the Notification Pattern.  You can't call `StateHasChanged` in a child to force a render of the parent component.

Add an event to your `TagService`.  It should look something like this.  Note the private setter on `ErrorMessage`.  It can only be set or reset through the methods that trigger the event.

```cs
public class TagService
{
    public event EventHandler? StateChanged;

    public string? ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    public void SetErrorMessage(string? message)
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = message;
        this.StateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void ResetErrorMessage()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = null;
        this.StateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here's my `MainLayout`.  Note the event handler set up for the `TagService` event [and `IDisposable` to unhook the handler when the component is disposed].  The handler simply calls `StateHasChanged` to update the Component UI.

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject TagService TagService
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>SO77097917</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            @if (this.TagService.ErrorMessage != null)
            {
                    <span class="text-danger">@this.TagService.ErrorMessage</span>
            }
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.TagService.StateChanged += this.OnStateChanged;

    private void OnStateChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose()
        => this.TagService.StateChanged -= this.OnStateChanged;
}
```

And my `Index` to demo it working:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject TagService TagService
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="SetMessage">Set Error</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ResetMessage">Clear Error</button>
</div>
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private void SetMessage()
        => this.TagService.SetErrorMessage($"ERROR!");

    private void ResetMessage()
        => this.TagService.ResetErrorMessage();

}
```

Comment: "You need to implement what is commonly known as the Notification Pattern"... Where can I learn more about the "Notification Pattern"? Do you have any sources you recommend? I'm struggling to find more information on it. This answer, as well as your others on the same topic, are great by the way. +1.

Comment: @Frosch - I may have overdone the commonly!  Search on here [Stack Overflow] and Bing. "Blazor Notification Pattern"  It's a derivation of the Observer Pattern, and simpler to implement than Flux.  Their basic premise to tame the unrestricted mutation beast at the heart of most applications.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [cascading values and parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Here is an example of how this can work, though you would obviously need to figure out how to implement it correctly in the context of your code:

**Your razor_header page**

```
@inject TagService TagService

@*This should probably be placed in your _MainLayout (or wherever appropriate), 
wrapped around your header and body sections.*@

<CascadingValue Value="TagService">     
    <Razor_page_1 OnStateHasChanged="OnStateHasChanged"/>
    <div>
        <h2>@TagService.Message_Main</h2>        
    </div>
</CascadingValue> 

@code{
    private void OnStateHasChanged()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

**Your razor_page_1**

```
<h1>Razor_page_1</h1>

<button onclick="@Task_1">
    Task 1
</button>
    
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public TagService TagService { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnStateHasChanged { get; set; }

    public async Task Task_1() 
    {
        //some code
        await Task.Delay(1000); //mimicking your "some code"
        if(error1_condition==true)
        {
          TagService.Message_Main=error1_text; //error1 should be shown in the header
          await OnUpdated();
        }
    }

    private async Task OnUpdated()
    {
        await OnStateHasChanged.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how those async functions are called the problem could be that you are not in the renderer context. Try to replace `StateHasChanged();` with `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`
This will ensure that StateHasChanged is executed in the right context.