# Can the body (I mean the current page which is selected) in Blazor be automatically updated when the value of a selectinput on the Navbar changes?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

The scenario is as follows: Blazor Server App with the default template. On the Navbar I inserted a SelectInput to change the year (e.g. 2023, 2024 etc.). Various razor pages can be displayed in the body which show, in a grid, data relating to the year selected in the Navbar. What I can't do is: update the page when the select changes and consequently EF has to re-execute the query to show the correct data in the grid.

Navbar component:

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" Value="currentEf" ValueExpression="@(() => efSel)" ValueChanged="@((int anno) => MyChangeEvent(anno))">
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
            <option value="2024">2024</option>
            <option value="2025">2025</option>
        </InputSelect>

    @code {
    
        int efSel;

    public static int currentEf;

    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (currentEf == 0)
        {
            currentEf = DateTime.Now.Year;
        } 

    }

    private void MyChangeEvent(int value)
    {
        currentEf = value;
        efSel = value;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

On Index component (just to check if value change), but page don't refresh!

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<label>Year Selected: @YearSelected.ToString()</label>


@code {


    int YearSelected;


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        YearSelected = NavMenu.currentEf;
    }

  
}
```

Comment: See this recent question and my answer.  It shows how to do it the other way, i.e. page to header, but the pattern is the same.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/77097917/13065781.  If this fits, we can close the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer based on my answer to this similar question.

[In my Blazor server app, I want to show messages of razor.cs pages in the header. But I cannot pass the messages from the razor pages to the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097917/in-my-blazor-server-app-i-want-to-show-messages-of-razor-cs-pages-in-the-header)

First the state object with an event and setter.

```cs
public class YearProvider
{
    public int Year { get; private set; } = DateTime.Now.Year;

    public event EventHandler? YearChanged;

    public void SetYear(int year)
    {
        this.Year = year;
        this.YearChanged?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

DI setup:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<YearProvider>();
```

NavMenu:

```cs
@inject YearProvider YearProvider

<InputSelect TValue="int" class="form-select" @bind-Value:get="this.YearProvider.Year" @bind-Value:set="this.YearProvider.SetYear">
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2025">2025</option>
</InputSelect>

//...
```

And Index, and any other page that needs to know about the data change:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject YearProvider YearProvider
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="alert alert-primary">
Year : @this.YearProvider.Year
</div>

@code {

    //registers the handler with the event
    protected override void OnInitialized()
     => this.YearProvider.YearChanged += this.OnYearChanged;

     // The handler refreahes the page
    private void OnYearChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.StateHasChanged();

    // Deregisters the handler when the component is disposed
    public void Dispose()
     => this.YearProvider.YearChanged -= this.OnYearChanged; 
}
```