# Interactive rendering or updating On Control

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

I have an issue where somethings are updated and others are not.

When I press the "Set MOTD" Button in the Settings.razor page it **does** update the "inputMOTD" to what you typed, but the "motd" variable that the MainLayout.razor uses to display the MOTD does not updated unless I refresh the page.

my project is globally set to InteractiveServer.

I have highlighted the references to what I am talking about..

[Image of the Settings Page and seeing the MainLayout at the same time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oCDn.png)

This is my Settings.razor page in the Components/Pages:

```
@page "/settings"

<PageTitle>Settings</PageTitle>

@*This is the HTML setup of the page*@
<h1 class="text-center">Site Settings Page</h1>
<hr />

<div class="d-grid justify-content-center m-5">
    <label class="text-primary">Please enter the message of the day:</label>
    <input @bind="inputMOTD" placeholder="ie.. Today's message of the day..." type="text" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SetMotd">Set MOTD</button>
</div>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h2 class="text-danger">Reload page to take effect!</h2>
</div>

@code
{
    public static string inputMOTD { get; set; }

    public static string motd { get; set; } = "Hello there, this is a sample MOTD!";

    public void SetMotd()
    {
        motd = inputMOTD;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the MainLayout.razor layout in the Components/Layout:

```
@using MistoSite.Components.Pages
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@* Ultimately the UI *@
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        @* This is the entire top row *@
        <div id="container" class="top-row px-4 d-flex flex-row align-items-end justify-content-between">
            @* This is the message of the day *@

            <p id="box" class="text-white text-decoration-underline">@Settings.motd</p>

            @* This is the displayed username *@
            <p class="text-white">
                <a class="text-white" href="/settings">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
                        <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8m8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1"/>
                    </svg>
                    Logged in: User1
                </a>
                | Date: @DateTime.Now
            </p>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

My App.razor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MistoSite.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer"/>
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to set the MainLayout.razor layout component itself to have a rendermode: InteractiveServer, and that did not work, so I set the project to be globally InteractiveServer. I have tried to have reference from the Settings.razor page code in the code block of the MainLayout but that did nothing, What I have done was set the MOTD in the MainLayout.razor to Settings.motd because it is initialized statically in the Settings.razor page code.

I need the "Set Motd" button from the settings page to set the displaying MOTD in the MainLayout.razor layout to update when I press it and not after a page refresh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In my Blazor server app, I want to show messages of razor.cs pages in the header. But I cannot pass the messages from the razor pages to the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097917/in-my-blazor-server-app-i-want-to-show-messages-of-razor-cs-pages-in-the-header)

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite know if this IS the issue but StateHasChanged usually must be invoked async

```
public async void SetMotd()
{
    motd = inputMOTD;
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

so this might solve it

Comment: Thank you for the help. It unfortunately did not solve the problem, but definitely going in the right direction.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. Sorry that I didnt respond. I was on Vacation