# Blazor subscribing to service not updating

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Within my Blazor app I created a notifications service that should show notifications when a user completes a task. I want to display this in my layout file. However, when i push a few notifications they don't show up immediately, they only show when i refresh the page. This is how i have written it:
INotificationService:

```
    public interface INotificationService
    {
        public Task SendNotification(string message, NotificationType messageType);
        public Task<List<Notification>> GetNotifications();
        public Task RemoveOldestNotification();
        event Action OnChange;
    }
```

NotificationService:

```
    private List<Notification> notifications = new();
    public event Action OnChange;

    public Task SendNotification(string message, NotificationType messageType)
    {
        notifications.Add(new Notification { message = message, messageType = messageType });
        StateChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<List<Notification>> GetNotifications()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(notifications);
    }

    public Task RemoveOldestNotification()
    {
        notifications.RemoveAt(0);
        StateChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    private void StateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

MainLayout.razor

```
@using Design_A_Bear.Services
@using Design_A_Bear.Models
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject INotificationService NotificationService
<div>
    <div>
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    @foreach (var notification in notifications)
    {
        <p class="bg-danger">@notification.message</p>
    }
    <main class="mainPage">
        <article class=" px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="fw-bold">Design A Bear - 2023</p>
        <p class="fw-bold">Made by Mateusz Kroplewski</p>

    </footer>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

@code
{
    private List<Notification> notifications;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        NotificationService.OnChange += OnNotify;
        notifications = await NotificationService.GetNotifications();

        notifications.Add(new Notification { message = "Hello", messageType = NotificationType.Success });
        notifications.Add(new Notification { message = "Hello", messageType = NotificationType.Success });
        notifications.Add(new Notification { message = "Hello", messageType = NotificationType.Success });
        notifications.Add(new Notification { message = "Hello", messageType = NotificationType.Success });

    }
    public async void OnNotify()
    {
        // Ensure notifications are fetched again when notified
        notifications = await NotificationService.GetNotifications();

        // Force a UI update
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

When i run the push notification function from a different page i get no errors but the notifications dont update. I see them when i refresh the page. I think i have done something wrong with the action maybe. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I try and send these notifications from the client app like this:
ClientNotificationService:

```
    public class ClientNotificationService(HttpClient httpClient) : INotificationService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = httpClient;

        public async Task SendNotification(string message, NotificationType messageType)
        {   
            Notification notification = new Notification { message = message, messageType = messageType };
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Notification", notification);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to send notification. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Notification>> GetNotifications()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Notification>>("api/Notification");
            return response;
        }

        public async Task RemoveOldestNotification()
        {
            var response = _httpClient.DeleteAsync("api/Notification");
            if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to remove notification. Status code: {response.Result.StatusCode}");
            }
        }

        public event Action? OnChange;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NotificationController(INotificationService notificationService) : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetNotifications()
        {
            var notifications = await notificationService.GetNotifications();
            return Ok(notifications);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SendNotification(string message, NotificationType messageType)
        {
            await notificationService.SendNotification(message, messageType);
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveOldestNotification()
        {
            await notificationService.RemoveOldestNotification();
            return Ok();
        }
    }
``
```

Comment: Throwing spaghetti, here.  Try `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`.  I can't test your code, but I don't think Blazor likes `async void`.

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work

Comment: I can see two implementations of the `INotificationService`.  Which one are you using?  "When I run the push notification function from a different page" Where?  You show no example of this.  And to which `INotificationService`?

Comment: This example shows a simple *Notification Pattern* implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099466/13065781.

Comment: its a blazor web app project so i need a service for both client and server. Most of my pages and in the client so i use the client implementation which hits the controller and adds it to the server one as im displaying them in the server layout file