C# Blazor .net 8 Service feature to access changes in mainlayouts @body and apply to a component in Mainlayout
I've referenced my code from Here and have a follow up
Attempting to access changed infomation in MainLayout based on changes in the @body
Mainlayout with NavPathComponent
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <NavPathComponent />
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>



        <footer style="background-color:#3a0647; position: fixed;bottom: 0; width: -webkit-fill-available; padding:5px;">
            <div class="logo-footer">
                <a href="https://bhinc.com/" target="_blank">
                    <img src="Images/bh-logo-light.svg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </main>

</div>


My component.razor with what I want to update based on @vody changes
@inject NavigablePathService NavigablePath
@implements IDisposable

<h3>NavPathComponent</h3>
<div class="col top-row px-4">
    <p>
        @if (NavigablePath.NavigablePath != null)
        {
            @foreach (string folder in NavigablePath.NavigablePath.Split("\\"))
            {
                <label style="cursor: pointer;color:blue;">@(folder)</label>
                <label> > </label>
            }
        }
    </p>
</div>

@code {
    public Func<Task> NavPathChange { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavPathChange = async () =>
        {
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };
        NavigablePath.NavigablePathSelector += NavPathChange;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        NavigablePath.NavigablePathSelector -= NavPathChange;
    }
}


My service.cs
public class NavigablePathService
{
    public string NavigablePath { get; set; }
    public Func<Task> NavigablePathSelector { get; set; }


    public async Task ChangePath(string newPath)
    {
        NavigablePath = newPath;
        await NavigablePathSelector.Invoke();
    }
}

The issue I run into is that Func is null when I call it from my OnIntialize in my @page
protected override void OnInitialized()
{

    navigablePathService.ChangePath("test\\banana");
}

First is this the right practive I attempted Casacading Value nesting a this Value="this" in MainLayout that didn't make much sense to me.
Would adding a constructor to my service and injecting it with a Func be a thing?
public NavigablePathService(Func<Task> navigablePathSelector)
{
    NavigablePathSelector = navigablePathSelector;
}


See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099466/13065781 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258228/13065781 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562295/13065781 on using the notification pattern to achieve what you want.

You could try this code:
MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>NavPathApp</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <NavPathComponent />
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

NavPathComponent.razor:
@inject NavPathApp.Services.NavigablePathService NavigablePath
@implements IDisposable

<h3>NavPathComponent</h3>
<div class="col top-row px-4">
    <p>
        @if (NavigablePath.NavigablePath != null)
        {
            @foreach (string folder in NavigablePath.NavigablePath.Split("\\"))
            {
                <label style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;">@(folder)</label>
                <label> > </label>
            }
        }
    </p>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("NavPathComponent: Subscribing to OnNavigablePathChanged event...");
        NavigablePath.OnNavigablePathChanged += UpdateNavPath;
    }

    private async Task UpdateNavPath()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("NavPathComponent: Event triggered, updating state...");
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("NavPathComponent: Unsubscribing from OnNavigablePathChanged event...");
        NavigablePath.OnNavigablePathChanged -= UpdateNavPath;
    }
}

NavigablePathService.cs:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NavPathApp.Services
{
    public class NavigablePathService
    {
        public string NavigablePath { get; set; }
        public event Func<Task> OnNavigablePathChanged;

        public async Task ChangePath(string newPath)
        {
            NavigablePath = newPath;
           // Console.WriteLine($"Path changed to: {NavigablePath}");
            if (OnNavigablePathChanged != null)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("Invoking OnNavigablePathChanged event...");
                await OnNavigablePathChanged.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}

TestPage.razor:
@page "/test"
@inject NavPathApp.Services.NavigablePathService navigablePathService

<h3>Test Page</h3>

<button @onclick="ChangePath">Change Path</button>

@code {
    private async Task ChangePath()
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("TestPage: Changing path to test\\banana...");
        await navigablePathService.ChangePath("test\\banana");
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       // Console.WriteLine("TestPage: Initializing and setting path to initial\\path...");
        // Initial path setup if needed
        await navigablePathService.ChangePath("initial\\path");
    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<NavigablePathService>();

Result:

