How can I invoke StateHasChanged() or update my UI from an implemented interface within a .net Blazor .RAZOR page?
I have a Blazor Server application. With this application, I am "talking" with MistralAI. This REST API endpoint has a streaming token you can set that will allow it to "stream" responses to you.
In my application, I have a service that contacts MistralAI for this conversation. I have implemented the Observer pattern so that I can update my .RAZOR page whenever I get a response from MistralAI:
MyService.cs:
public class MyService {
    private List<Reader> readers = new List<Reader>();
    private AIResponse response;
    public async Task<AIResponse> myTask(){
        Reader newReader = new MyPage();
        readers.Add(newReader);
        // Send requests to and receive responses from MistralAI
        addWord(receivedJSONString);
        notifyReaders();
    }

    public void notifyReaders()
    {
        foreach (var reader in readers) {
            reader.updateWords(response);
        }
    }

    public void addWord(AIResponse newResponse)
    {
        response = newResponse;
    }
}

public interface Reader {
    void updateResponses(AIResponse newResponse);
}

MyPage.razor
@implements Reader
<div>
    @foreach(var newResponse in responses){
        @newResponse
    }
</div>
@code {
    private List<AIResponse> responses { get; set; } = new List<AIResponse>();
    private async Task QueryAI(){
        AIResponse streamingAIResponse = await myService.myTask(someString);
    }

    public void updateResponses(AIResponse newResponse){
        responses.Add(newResponse);
        Console.Write(newResponse);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

I can successfully get the responses to my .RAZOR page, I can see them in the console when I Console.Write, but I cannot update the UI with the new content; I keep getting the error The render handle is not yet assigned.
So, how can I use the StateHasChanged() from within my implemented interface?
Or, how can I update my UI with the new content?

UPDATES:
@code {
    [Inject]
    public IMyService myService { get; set; }

    private String queryString { get; set; } = null;

    private List<AIResponse> responses { get; set; } = new List<AIResponse>();

    private Conversation conversation { get; set; }

    private ElementReference aiQuery;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (conversation == null)
        {
            conversation = new onversation();
            conversation.messages = new List<Message>();
        }
    }

    private async Task QueryAI()
    {
        Message message = new Message("user", queryString);
        conversation.messages.Add(message);


        StreamingQueryResponse streamingAIResponse = await myService.getStreamingAIResponseAsync(conversation);
    }

    public void updateWords(StreamingQueryResponse newResponse)
    {
        responses.Add(newResponse);
        Console.Write(newResponse);
    }
}


You await myService.MyTask in MyPage, but there's no definition.  You define updateResponses and QueryAI but don't show how they are called.  The error message says you're trying to render the component before it's been attsched to the RenderTree by the Renderer.  Are you trying to create the component manually?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I added my @code section of my component to my post. I'm not sure how a person would manually create a component. my Index.razor has a sub-component, which in turn has a sub-component, which has MyPage.razor as another sub-component. Plus, I cannot wait for MyService to return as it is constantly getting updates from the MistralAI web service. I need to send the responses to my component as my service is getting it.

Judging from the blazor lifecycle, could try notify components of service changes  through event handling.

The observer pattern generally has a service with an event you subscribe to in your consuming page.
The following isn't working code, but should have all the elements to understand the service / page relationship:
-the service does all the API interactions.  It sets up the async call, and every time new message info comes in, it fires the event
-the page or component subscribes to the service event by adding an event handler to process each message, and (importantly) removes it in Dispose.
MistralService.cs
namespace MyApp.Code
{
    public class MistralService
    {
            public event Action<string> OnMessageReceived;

            public async Task StartStreamingAsync(string apiKey)
            {
                using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "mistral.api/endpoint");
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");

                using var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

                using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    OnMessageReceived?.Invoke(line);
                }
        }
    }
}

ConsumingPage.razor
@using MyApp.Code
@inject MistralService MS

<h3>ConsumingPage</h3>
<button @onclick=StartStreaming>Start Streaming</button>
<div>@streamedText</div>
@code {
    string streamedText = "";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        MS.OnMessageReceived += HandleMessage;
    }
    async Task StartStreaming()
    {
        await MS.StartStreamingAsync("theAPIkey");
    }
    async void HandleMessage(string Message)
    {
        streamedText += Message + "<br/>";
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        MS.OnMessageReceived -= HandleMessage;
    }
}

Remember to add MistralService to your service in Program.cs:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddScoped<MistralService>();


This worked great, thank you! One thing about Dispose() though, it never gets called. Any idea why?

Dispose should be called when you're done with the page, say when you navigate or close the page.  Or if you consume the service in a component, when the component is removed from the UI.

You can't do this - manually create a component.  That's the job of the Renderer.
Reader newReader = new MyPage();

You need to decouple the service that receives the messages and the UI component that displays them.
To do this your service exposes a NewMessage event that anyone who want to receive a notification subscribes to - in this case your display components.
This is the Blazor Notification Pattern.  You can see an implementation example here that you can adapt to fit your needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562295/13065781
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099466/13065781
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449070/13065781


But I did do this. I implemented the observer pattern, and now my service is successfully sending updates to my UI component. All I need to do is to tell the UI to update itself.

Also, the three articles you linked all involve component-to-component interaction. This is not what I want. I want service-to-component interaction.

[Polite]  They are relevant.  They are Compoinent -> Service -> Component. They demonstrate how to implement notifications from a service to a component, and the pattern to use in a component.  As shown in Benny's answer.

I appreciate your input, and have switched to using @Bennyboy1973's solution.
