Blazor isnt re-rendering Component after receiving a Paramameter(Hashset) from Service
My Blazor component is not being re-rendered after receiving a new value for its hashset parameter from a service I have implemented. The parameter is set by an event in the service.
This is the main page where my component in question "GenericGridComponent" is located. When rendering the page, a database query is called by await Task.Run(() => DataExchange.AccessData<fcPersons>());, which stores a hashset from a database in the DataExchange service.
@inject DataExchange DataExchange
@rendermode InteractiveServer

    <GenericGridComponent
        T="fcPersonen">

    </GenericGridComponent>



@code {

    protected async  override OnAfterRender(Boolean firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender == true)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => DataExchange.AccessData<fcPersonen>());
        }
    }
}

In the GenericGridComponent, an event is bound in OnAfterRender, which assigns a new value to the hashset parameter Elements by the service. The value is successfully assigned to the parameter, but this does not re-render the user interface of my component. In this case, I would like to dispense with the StateHasChanged() method, because as far as I know, Blazor should automatically register a change to a parameter and re-render the specific content.
@typeparam T where T :class, new()
@inject DataExchange DataExchange

@using System.Reflection

@if (Elements != null)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead class="thead">
        
        <tr>

            @foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Elements.First().GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                <th scope="col">
                        
                    <div style="width:fit-content;">
                            
                        <p>@propertyInfo.Name</p>

                    </div>

                </th>
            }

        </tr>

        </thead>
        
        <tbody>

            <Virtualize TItem="T" Context="obj" Items="Elements">

                <tr>

                    @foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        
                        <td>@propertyInfo.GetValue(obj)</td>
                    }

                </tr>

        </Virtualize>

        </tbody>

    </table>
}

@code {

    protected override void OnAfterRender(Boolean firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender == true)
        {
            DataExchange.DataChanged += DataChanged;
        }
    }

    private void DataChanged()
    {
        Elements = DataExchange.GetData<T>();
    }

    private HashSet<T>? Elements { get; set; }
}

It was expected that the component would redraw itself due to the change in the bound property.


It was expected that the component would redraw itself due to the change in the bound property.

Running code in OnAfterRender does exactly what is says on the tin.  It's run after the component has rendered.  There's no automatic state mutation detector in a component. Mutate the state after you've rendered, and you need to trigger a render manually [i.e. call StateHasChanged] to get the component display to reflect the new state, and for any parameter changes to be detected by the Renderer and cascaded to child components.
So how do you prevent this?
Don't do mutation stuff in OnAfterRender.  Write mutation code in OnInitialized{Async} or OnParametersSet{Async}.  StateHasChanged will be called at the end of the process: no need for manual rendering.
A good general rule: if you need to call StateHasChanged then your component logic is probably flawed.  The main exception is event handlers where you do need to trigger a manual render if the handler mutates the component state.
The reasons are explained in the following articles:

Should I use OnAfterRenderAsync instead of OnInitializedAsync?
Is the NET 8 Blazor web app template flawed?
Blazor - should I read in my data in OnInitializedAsync() or OnAfterRenderAsync(true)

Or search "[blazor] OnAfterRender" for more.
Additional Information for the Comment
There's no "observer" watching a component's state and automatically triggering StateHasChanged.
UI events - such as a button click or invoking an EventCallback, are invoked by the renderer through the registered IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync.  In ComponentBase this calls StateHasChanged automatically. Link to code
Event handlers called from DI Services and other services such as timers are invoked directly, so there's no automatic call to StateHasChanged.  You need to do it manually, and often through ComponentBase.InvokeAsync to ensure it gets invoked on the SynchronisationContext. Link to code
What you are talking about is an implementation of the Notification Pattern.  You can see implementation examples here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562295/13065781
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77099466/13065781
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76449070/13065781


the actual goal was to centralize Parameters in a service that are needed in different components, in order to directly access these Parameters from different Components via @inject Service i defined the Parameters diretly in the Service.
In my case, the parameters are changed by the service itself. Since these service parameters are directly referenced in my components, I assumed that Blazor would automatically re-render the associated content after a parameter was changed.
If I have understood correctly, you can only work with a StateHasChanged in this case and my concept does not work.

Correct in your last statement.  I've some additional information to the answer with links to what I call the Notification Pattern and an explanation as to why you need to call StateHasChanged.

Supposing that DataExchange.DataChanged is your event Action? in the service and it is indeed invoked after requesting the data and updating the Elements, try subscribing to the event in your OnInitialized() lifecycle method. And add StateHasChanged(); at the end of your handling method DataChanged().
Also it is a good approach to implement IDisposable in your component GenericGridComponent and remove the event subscription from the stack when disposing of the component.
This could be a solution:
@implements IDisposable

//-----------------------
//rest of your razor code
//-----------------------

@code {
    private HashSet<T>? Elements { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DataExchange.DataChanged += DataChanged;
    }

    private void DataChanged()
    {
        Elements = DataExchange.GetData<T>();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DataExchange.DataChanged -= DataChanged;
    }
}

